Change rendered file type from Quarto in RStudio
I have been a R Markdown user and want to try Quarto.
In RStudio, you can select the output file type easily from the dropdown menu shown below (pdf, html, word).

If I use Quarto, there is no such an option. I have to manually change format: pdf to format: html in the file. Is there an option similar to R Markdown?


This is described in the docs: https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html#rendering
Simply add the desired formats to the YAML and the dropdown menu should now appear next to the Render button.
---
title: "test"
format:
  html: 
    code-fold: true
    html-math-method: katex
  pdf:
    geometry: 
      - top=30mm
      - left=30mm
  docx: default
    
---


